# Populating an HTML List using AJAX from DB and updating the newly selected value back to the DB

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, servlets, gson

I have been trying to dynamically populate a list from a DB using AJAX, and then saving the newly selected value of the list back to the DB using a servlet. What is the best way to do it?

This is the code I usually use to do the dynamic updating and populating (with Gson). But this won't work as the List has several values to be loaded from the DB.

AJAX

```
<script>

jQuery(function () {
    $('.clickable-row').click(function () {

   var $this = $(this),
            id = this.id;

        $.get("DynPopRemPersnSrvlt?idReminderLevel="+id, function (responseJson) {

            var array=[];            

           $.each(responseJson, function(index, item)
           {
             array[index]=item;
           });

            $('#firstNameTxt').val(array[1]);
            $('#lastNameTxt').val(array[2]);
            $('#designationTxt').val(array[3]);
            $('#emailTxt').val(array[4]);
            $('#levelLst').val(array[5]);

            $('#idReminderLevel').val(array[0]);

           });
    });
}); 

</script>
```

DynPopRemPersnSrvlt. This servlets gives the data for the AJAX.

```
  int idReminderLevel=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idReminderLevel"));

        ReminderPersonService remPService=new ReminderPersonService();

        List<String> remPersLst=new ArrayList<String>();     

        Reminderperson reminderPerson =remPService.findById(idReminderLevel);

        remPersLst.add(reminderPerson.getIdReminderLevel().toString());
        remPersLst.add(reminderPerson.getFirstName());
        remPersLst.add(reminderPerson.getLastName());
        remPersLst.add(reminderPerson.getDesignation());
        remPersLst.add(reminderPerson.getEmail());         
        remPersLst.add(reminderPerson.getReminderleveltype().getTypeName());

        String json=new Gson().toJson(remPersLst);        
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
```

What I want is to send a List like this from the servlet. Then retrieve it from the AJAX and then load all the values to an HTML List.

```
ArrayList<Reminderleveltype> rem=remPService.findAll();
```

An HTML list like this.

```
   <select id="levelLst" class="form-control input-md" name="levelLst">  

                  <option value="id1">First Level</option>
                  <option value="id2">Second Level</option> 
                  <option value="id3">Third Level</option> 

    </select>
```

Is it possible to Dynamically load the DBG table's "id" to the HTML list's "value" and the the DB table's "name" to the "text"("First Level" etc..) of the HTML List, and then get the selected value by "id" then update it back to DB?

Comment: How much you have done already and where you are having difficulty ..tell in brief

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can populate it dynamically. I have a suggestion for you, if your requirement is only to populate dropdown with key and value why using `list`? (getting and setting all the values in list unnecessarily) Go for map. Just put id and value in map.

After receiving gson data from ajax re-construct your select tag options and its values like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("DynPopRemPersnSrvlt?idReminderLevel="+id, function (responseJson) {   
       var $select = $('#levelLst');                           
       // Clear the existing values                        
       $select.find('option').remove();   
       $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {               
           $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);      
       });
     });
  });
});
```

So it will re populate the select box with new values.